# Fire is very pixelated in final render

Tags: animation

I work in internal, and I made a model shoot fire. For some reason it looks very low res. What can I do to fix this? an image has been attached:
[image]

Comment: Please don't double-post. Use the "edit" link below your original question instead.

Comment: I didn't this is a different question. That other question is asking why it's blocky, mine's is a rendering problem. The fire on mine doesn't look blocky.

Answer (score 2):

You could increase the rendered fire quality in the physics tab

[image]

Comment: i did that. It still looks very pixelated.